# What's the difference between て言ってた vs ように言われた?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I have learned recently that ように can be used for advice, command, ask and so on. Is there a difference between て言ってた and ように言われた? For example:

> 私はママにTVを消すように言われた。
>
> ママは私にTVを消しなさいって言ってた。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passive or active voice and indirect or direct quote.
The first sentence translates to

> I was told by my mother to turn the TV off.

The second one to

> Mother told me: Turn the TV off.

と or って follows a direct quote.

Comment: which one of them is more used on daily basis?

Comment: Both are used pretty much all the time. Direct (or verbatim) quotes are used a lot more in Japanese than in English.

Comment: Thanks, I will clarify my question. Is there a Japanese nuance to choose one on top of the other that you are aware of?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence litteraly means 
'I have been told by Mama to switch off the TV'. It is a passive form, that's why いう (to say, to tell) becomes いわれる (to be told).

The second sentence litteraly means 'Mama told me to switch off the TV'. Here the sentence is active and the って is the quotation particle (note that one usually prefers と instead of って in a formal context).